# Matrix gauss-jordan / gaussian

Tags: matrices

I am a bit confused in terms of doing gaussian and gauss-jordan elimination for a system of equations.

For example let's say we have the following system of equations:

[image: equation]

We get the following:

[image: equation2]

Once we 0 out all the rows in the first column below 1, do we move on to the 2 (2nd column) and begin 0 out all the rows below it, or do we move diagonally to the -6 and 0 out its row?

And is it the same process for gaussian AND gauss-jordan? If someone can outline the process difference for both it'd be great.

Thanks.

Comment: You move to the  second row. But remember you can switch rows. If you interchange row 2 and 3, you automatically get a "1" for the second row, second column. Then you move on to the third row and your goal is to make the third column entry zero.

Comment: Second column of thge second row correct?

Comment: And is the above true for both Gaussian Eliminiation AND Gaussian Jordon Elimination (RRF VS RREF)

Comment: Yes. That's correct. Basically (from wiki), "The leading coefficient (the first nonzero number from the left, also called the pivot) of a nonzero row is always strictly to the right of the leading coefficient of the row above it (some texts add the condition that the leading coefficient must be 1.[1])."

Comment: The difference between RRF and RREF is that for RREF the leading coefficient for every row is 1.

Comment: So then whats the difference in process of Gaussian Elimination (RRF) vs Gaussian Jordon Elimination (RREF)?

Comment: So then it's the same process but different rules?

Comment: They are essentially the same. Using row operations to convert a matrix to REF form is called Gaussian Elimination. If you further convert it to a RREF (by using the same row operations), the process is called Gauss Jordan. It really just depends on your goal (RREF vs REF). But both "methods" use the same row operations. If it confuses you, you can use the more general "Gaussian elimination" for both RREF, and REF.

Comment: So if I go to RREF, and realize the solution is inconsistent and I need to go back in REF, am I able to back track?

Comment: I am not sure why you need to do that if the system has no solutions. It won't give you additional information. When you row reduce, you do it in two parts: The first is to bring it to REF form using row operations. From here, you can tell whether a system has a solution, has no solutions, or has infinite solutions. The second part is to find these solutions (if they exist). You do this by continuing the row operations until you reach RREF (which gives you explicit solutions).

Comment: Can you show me the gaussian elimination to REF and RREF for this? I got fractions solutions and incorrect answers, I'm struggling with this one.

Comment: I will add an answer tomorrow. Keep a lookout.

Comment: What I got was http://i59.tinypic.com/330vgh4.png but I think this is incorrect because when I subbed it in one of the original equations I didn't get a correct answer

Comment: Just to make sure I am correctly following the steps:


1) First go to leading value of first row
2) If the leading value isn't 1, make it one by subtracting from another row if need be, or dividing
3) Make the column for that leading value all 0 other than the leading value
4) Move on to the leading value of the second row (which will be in the middle)
5) Repeat step 2-3
6) Move on to the leading value of the third row (which will be end)
7) Repeat step 2-3
This gives us RREF

Comment: Your method is correct. Your solution is pretty correct but I think you may have mistyped something. I've added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your row reduced matrix is the following:
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & -5              & 2               \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \frac{17}{7} & -\frac{5}{7} \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -\frac{5}{7} &  -\frac{1}{7}               \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0               & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, this yields:
$$
\begin{align} x_1 - 5 x_4 &= 2  \\
          x_2 + \frac{17}{7}x_4 &= \frac{-5}{7} \\
          x_3 - \frac{5}{7} &= \frac{-1}{7} \end{align}$$

You can either set $x_i$ for $i \in \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ to a free variable, substitute that in and solve for the rest. It's easiest to do that for either $x_4$ or $x_3$

In your comments, I think you had the first equation wrong. Its written as $$x_1 = 2 - 4x_4$$

Comment: Thanks so much. Do you mind if I keep this thread posted for other related questions?

Comment: If my answer was suitable for this question, you can mark it as the "answer". For other, related questions , its better to create a new thread as per SE guidelines

Comment: I think I did. I clicked the green arrow.

Comment: Can you show your work by any chance?